# Add Service to application scope post bootstrapping Ng2

Tags: angular, angular-services

I'm building an Angular2 application whereby I need to load from a multitude of different services a it loads sub applications. It would be ideal if i could dynamically add a Service to the application scope at runtime, i.e. after bootstrapping has occurred but I'm struggling to find a practical method.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please check

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Injector-class.html

you may register new services by resolveAndCreate.

Here is a good explanation how DI work :)

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

A service is only instantiated when a component that depend on it is instantiated - so in that sense they are dynamically created and there is no bootstrapping process that pre-creates all of the services in your app. I can't imagine a scenario where a component wouldn't know it's dependencies - so if you write your components with service dependencies as normal Angular2 will take care of instantiating those services when they are needed.

Also the way scopes work in Angular2 is different from Angular.js - I'm not quite sure what you mean by application scope in this context. At the end of the day services are just classes that are instantiated by the injector, and you can either get the framework to inject them for you, access to the injector directly if you need it (import {injector} from 'angular2/angular2'), or instantiate an instance of the class yourself with new() - but this defeats the purpose of dependency injection which is to remove the responsibility for dependency instantiation onto the framework.